# Negation and De Morgan's Law not part of C++20 partial ordering by constraints

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts, demorgans-law

The rules for [partial ordering by constraints](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.order) refer to AND and OR, but do not refer to NOT:

> ```
> 13.5.4 Partial ordering by constraints [temp.constr.order]
> (1.2) ...
> - The constraint A ∧ B subsumes A, but A does not subsume A ∧ B.
> - The constraint A subsumes A ∨ B, but A ∨ B does not subsume A.
> ```

These rules are based on the definitions of [atomic constraints](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.atomic) and [constraints normalization](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.normal#def:constraint,normalization):

> ```
> 13.5.3 Constraint normalization [temp.constr.normal]
> 1 The normal form of an expression E is a constraint that is defined
>   as follows:
> (1.1) The normal form of an expression ( E ) is the normal form of E.
> (1.2) The normal form of an expression E1 || E2 is the disjunction
>       of the normal forms of E1 and E2.
> (1.3) The normal form of an expression E1 && E2 is the conjunction
>       of the normal forms of E1 and E2.
> ```

Negation (i.e. !E1) is specifically NOT handled.

Thus the following code is using partial ordering correctly:

```
void foo(auto i) requires std::integral<decltype(i)> {
    std::cout << "integral 1" << std::endl;
}

void foo(auto i) requires std::integral<decltype(i)> && true {
    std::cout << "integral 2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo(0); // integral 2
}
```

while this code fails with ambiguity:

```
template<typename T>
concept not_integral = !std::integral<T>;

template<typename T>
concept not_not_integral = !not_integral<T>;

void foo(auto i) requires not_not_integral<decltype(i)> {
    std::cout << "integral 1" << std::endl;
}

void foo(auto i) requires std::integral<decltype(i)> && true {
    std::cout << "integral 2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo(0);
}
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/RYjqr2

---

Above causes De Morgan's Law not to work for concepts:

```
template<class P>
concept has_field_moo_but_not_foo
     = has_field_moo<P> && !has_field_foo<P>;
```

is not equivalent to:

```
template<class P>
concept has_field_moo_but_not_foo
     = !(has_field_foo<P> || !has_field_moo<P>);
```

the first would participate in partial ordering while the latter would not.

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/aRhmyy

---

Was the decision, *not to handle negation as part of constraint normalization*, taken in order to ease the implementation for compiler vendors? or is there a logical flaw with trying to support it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Was the decision, *not to handle negation as part of constraint normalization*, taken in order to ease the implementation for compiler vendors?

Yes. This generalizes to requiring a SAT solver in the compiler.

There was an example added in [[temp.constr.op]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr#op-5) to demonstrate this, although it does not provide the rationale for the decision:

> ```
> template <class T> concept sad = false;
>
> template <class T> int f1(T) requires (!sad<T>);
> template <class T> int f1(T) requires (!sad<T>) && true;
> int i1 = f1(42);        // ambiguous, !sad<T> atomic constraint expressions ([temp.constr.atomic])
>                         // are not formed from the same expression
>
> template <class T> concept not_sad = !sad<T>;
> template <class T> int f2(T) requires not_sad<T>;
> template <class T> int f2(T) requires not_sad<T> && true;
> int i2 = f2(42);        // OK, !sad<T> atomic constraint expressions both come from not_­sad
>
> template <class T> int f3(T) requires (!sad<typename T::type>);
> int i3 = f3(42);        // error: associated constraints not satisfied due to substitution failure
>
> template <class T> concept sad_nested_type = sad<typename T::type>;
> template <class T> int f4(T) requires (!sad_nested_type<T>);
> int i4 = f4(42);        // OK, substitution failure contained within sad_­nested_­type
> ```

In particular, note the difference between `f3` and `f4`. Does `requires !sad<typename T::type>` mean that there be no `sad` nested type, or that there be a nested type that is not `sad`? It actually means the latter, while the constraint on `f4` means the former.

Comment: That was quick! Trying to find the history for this or a discussion on the subject I reached: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1375r2.html for example but couldn't find a reference to this subject. If you have one this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @AmirKirsh There is no such history really - the example was added in response to [US111](https://github.com/cplusplus/nbballot/issues/110). Core in general does not add rationale for language features, so there is no rationale included in the standard.

Comment: This is a great reference! Worth adding the link into the answer. Working papers sometime detail the rationale behind a suggestion, so might be that it does appear somewhere. Or not.